# Correspondence between a maximum ratio and a metric

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, soft-question

Define

$$P=\left \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : x_i \geq 0,\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=1 \right \} \\
X=\{ (p,q) \in P \times P : q_i=0 \Rightarrow p_i=0 \}.$$

Or in words: $P$ is the set of all probability distributions on some set with $n$ elements, and $X$ is the set of pairs $(p,q)$ of such distributions such that $p$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $q$.

I'm looking at a function $f : X \to \mathbb{R},f((p,q))=\max_i \frac{p_i}{q_i}$, with the understanding $0/0=1$. I'd like to think of this as a kind of "distance" between the distributions $p$ and $q$ which bottoms out at $1$ when $p=q$. Note that $p=q$ is indeed the strict minimum of $f((\cdot,q))$.

Accordingly, is it possible to obtain a metric $d$ such that $\lim_{k \to \infty} f(p^{(k)},q)=1$ if and only if $\lim_{k \to \infty} d(p^{(k)},q)=0$?

It would be nice if such a $d$ did not depend explicitly on $n$. It would also be of interest if $d$ were merely "metric-like"; this is a soft concept, but for example the Kullback-Leibler divergence is "metric-like" in this sense.

A concrete idea that comes to mind is $d(p,q)=\| \log(p/q) \|_\infty$, which is of course a *bona fide* metric. However this is not necessarily just $\log f$, because it could be that $\max |\log(p/q)| = | \min \log(p/q)|$. Can that happen? If so does it break the desired convergence property? Finally, it would be *really* nice if these two had the same monotonicity structure, i.e. $f((p_1,q_1)) \leq f((p_2,q_2))$ if and only if $d(p_1,q_1) \leq d(p_2,q_2)$, though that may be too much to hope for.

Comment: Just woke up, so I'm most likely missing something. But why don't, say, total variation or Hellinger distances do the job? (or the asymmetric $\chi^2$, for that matter, which is more KL-like)

Comment: You mapping $f$ is, up to logarithm, called the Funk weak metric. You metric $d$ is known as Thompson metric. They are closely related, and usually the Funk and Thompson metrics comes together with the Hilbert metric. These are well studied objects. For references, I suggests the "Handbook of Hilbert Geometry" from Padadopoulos and Troyanov and the book "Nonlinear Perron-Frobenius theory" of Lemmens and Nussbaum.

Comment: @Surb Can you explain how this is the same as the Funk weak metric even with the maximization part? The definitions seem different to me (taking my definition from http://www.math.uni.lodz.pl/~sajmonw/mathbooks/Papadopoulos%20&%20Troyanov,%20From%20Funk%20to%20Hilbert%20Geometry.pdf )

Comment: Well the funk metric on the convex cone $\Bbb R^n_{++}=\{x\mid x_i>0,\forall i\}$ is defined as
$$\operatorname{Funk}(x,y) = \ln(\max_{i}x_i/y_i).$$
This definition can be extended to the whole nonnegative orthant by allowing $\operatorname{Funk}(x,y)$ to have infinite values. Now, $\|\ln(x)-\ln(y)\|_{\infty} = \max\{\operatorname{Funk}(x,y),\operatorname{Funk}(y,x)\}$ is the so-called Thompson metric and $d_H(x,y) = \operatorname{Funk}(x,y)+\operatorname{Funk}(y,x)$ is called the Hilbert projective metric.

Comment: @Surb I see, so this simplification (relative to the more general definition in the notes I gave) is just related to the particulars of the geometry of $\mathbb{R}^n_{++}$. That's great (and in fact most of the cases I'm dealing with are on $\mathbb{R}^n_{++}$, not merely $\mathbb{R}^n_+$). Feel free to transcribe this last comment into an answer!

Comment: @Ian regarding http://www.math.uni.lodz.pl/~sajmonw/mathbooks/Papadopoulos%20&%20Troyanov,%20From%20Funk%20to%20Hilbert%20Geometry.pdf , have a look at Example 4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f$ as well as the metric $d$ mentioned in OP are closely related to the geometry of cones.

More precisely, the Funk (weak) metric on the convex cone $\Bbb R^n_{++}=\{x\mid x_i>0,\forall i\}$ is defined as
$$\operatorname{Funk}(x,y) = \ln\Big(\max_{i=1,\ldots,n}\frac{x_i}{y_i}\Big).$$
In particular, $\operatorname{Funk}(x,y)=\ln(f(x,y))$. This definition can be extended to the whole nonnegative orthant (i.e. the closure of $\Bbb R_{++}^n$) by allowing $\operatorname{Funk}(x,y)$ to have infinite values. We refer to Chapter 2 of the [Handbook on Hilbert Geometry](http://www.ems-ph.org/books/book.php?proj_nr=184) by Papadopoulos and Troyanov for the technical details.

Now, note that 
$$d_T(x,y)=\|\ln(x)-\ln(y)\|_{\infty} = \max\big\{\operatorname{Funk}(x,y),\operatorname{Funk}(y,x)\big\}$$ is the so-called Thompson metric on $\Bbb R^n_{++}$. Furthermore, you might be interested by their projective counterpart which is defined as $$d_H(x,y) = \operatorname{Funk}(x,y)+\operatorname{Funk}(y,x)$$ and is called the Hilbert projective metric. For a smooth introduction to these metrics I strongly recommend the book on [Nonlinear Perron-Frobenius theory](http://www.cambridge.org/catalogue/catalogue.asp?isbn=9780521898812) by Lemmens and Nussbaum (Chapter 2 again).

Comment: I notice now that $\| \log(p/q) \|_\infty$ (which I mentioned in the question) is another way of defining the Thompson metric, since a minimizer of $\log(p_i/q_i)$ is a maximizer of $\log(q_i/p_i)$.

Comment: @Ian well, this is what I tried to explain in my answer, indeed $\ln(x)-\ln(y)=\ln(x/y)$.

Comment: Oh, I missed the first equality in $d_T$ somehow, zooming straight to the second one. Anyway, this is great, it may be a big help in my research.

Comment: @Ian May I ask you what topic are you researching on? Indeed, such metrics lie at the heart of mines which are concerned by the generalizations of the Perron-Frobenius theorem.

Comment: It's related to Markov chains. We've shown a result that can be stated in this language as "if a time-homogeneous Markov chain on a countable state space has an invariant distribution, then it converges to it monotonically in the Thompson metric". It was originally used just to prove some estimates, but we're trying to see if it has any deeper significance, generalizations, etc.

Comment: @Ian I see, then, if you don't know it already, I think you might be very interested by chapter 3 in the book "Non-negative Matrices and Markov Chains" of E. Senata who uses these metrics for the study of Markov chains.